# Using PCIe as an Interconnect Connection

Tags: cluster, pci-express

I was researching about connecting multiple server nodes together to share resources. I came up to this page: http://www.plxtech.com/applications/cloud

From what I read, I see this is possible.

Anyone tried this one before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly that a generic network can't bring you?  10G ethernet is where i would start if speeds is an issue.  I/O virtualazation is cool/useful, but it depends on what you're trying to do.